# Possible to reuse Flex library assets? (i.e. TitleWindow's closeButton)

Tags: apache-flex, action

I want to reuse the TitleWindow's closeButton inside a simple Flex component I am writing, but I'm having trouble getting it to compile. I copied the code that deals with the closeButton, which looks somewhat like this:

```
closeButton = new Button();
closeButton.styleName = new StyleProxy(this, closeButtonStyleFilters);

closeButton.upSkinName = "closeButtonUpSkin";
closeButton.overSkinName = "closeButtonOverSkin";
closeButton.downSkinName = "closeButtonDownSkin";
closeButton.disabledSkinName = "closeButtonDisabledSkin";
closeButton.skinName = "closeButtonSkin";
closeButton.explicitWidth = closeButton.explicitHeight = 16;
```

And referenced the Styles like this:

```
<mx:Metadata>
    [Style(name="closeButtonSkin", type="Class", inherit="no", states="up, over, down, disabled")]
    [Style(name="closeButtonDisabledSkin", type="Class", inherit="no")]
    [Style(name="closeButtonDownSkin", type="Class", inherit="no")]
    [Style(name="closeButtonOverSkin", type="Class", inherit="no")]
    [Style(name="closeButtonUpSkin", type="Class", inherit="no")]
</mx:Metadata>
```

But the compiler is complaining that it can't find the referenced styles, i.e.:

```
1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property disabledSkinName through a reference with static type mx.controls:Button.
```

I noticed that the TitleWindow/Panel source references an Assets.swf, and I am guessing that this may be the cause of my problems, but I am unsure.

Anyone have any ideas? Is this even possible, or am I wasting my time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Styles and properties are different.  You can't set styles using object property n otation.  Use the setStyle method.  LIke this:

```
closeButton.setStyle('upSkinName',closeButtonUpSkin)
closeButton.setStyle('overSkinName',closeButtonOverSkin)
```

And so on...  I only converted the first two.  The metadata is only used for code hinting, so that won't have any affect on your ability to compile ActionScript code.

Comment: I tried that, and got the same error. I don't think its the declaration, as I copied the first code snippet from the Flex Source. I get the following error: 
1120: Access of undefined property closeButtonDisabledSkin